# Finding optimal permutation via minimizing non-convex objective over Birkhoff polytope

Tags: optimization, permutations, non-convex-optimization, permutation-matrices, birkhoff-polytopes

Suppose function $f$ is non-convex and non-linear, $P$ is a permutation matrix and $x$ is input data. In this case, we consider a convex relaxation of $P$ by letting $P$ be in the set of [doubly stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) matrices,. How can one solve the following?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{P}{\text{minimize}} & f (P x)\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_i p_{ij} = \displaystyle\sum_j p_{ij} = 1\\ & p_{ij} \geq 0\end{array}$$

Is there a name for theses types of permutation optimization problems?

Comment: What does relaxing a matrix mean? You're relaxing the finite set of all permutation matrices of a given size.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo We are not optimizing over the set of permutation matrices, but over the set of Doubly-Stochastic-matrices, which are a convex relation of permutation matrices. In a permutation matrix every row and every column of a permutation matrix can contain exactly one nonzero entry,
which is 1, while with Doubly-Stochastic-matrices we drop this extra constraint.

Comment: You are optimising over the Birkhoff polytope, right?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes exactly

Comment: Isn't the Birkhoff polytope kind of the convex hull of the set of permutation matrices? Aren't permutation matrices doubly stochastic?

Comment: @yes the Birkhoff polytope is the convex hull of permutation matrices. I guess permutation matrices are a subset of the doubly stochastic matrices, but we are considering the entire set.

Comment: What else do you know about $f$? Polynomial, at least?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $f$ has the form of a neural network - non-linear, non-convex but differentiable